# How to shut down rethinkdb running on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, shutdown, rethinkdb

**Note**: We *love* RethinkDB but our *current* project does not use it so we need to free up resources on our local machine ...

We installed RethinkDB using **homebrew**:

```
brew update && brew install rethinkdb
```

And added the rethinkdb process to our plist as per the instructions in:
http://rethinkdb.com/docs/start-on-startup/

But now we need to shut it down to free-up the **8080** port for another service.

What command do we need to run? (*thanks!*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, I think, if you used `launchctl`:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rethinkdb.server.plist
```

Answer (score 19):

Do this in the terminal

check to see if you started it using brew

```
$ brew services list
```

stop rethinkdb:

```
$ brew services stop rethinkdb
```

restart:

```
$ brew services start rethinkdb
```